# How does the White UI Automation library use Castle DynamicProxy?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, castle-dynamicproxy

The [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) UI Automation library makes extensive use of the [Castle Project'](http://www.castleproject.org)s DynamicProxy 2. From what I understand, DynamicProxy is utilized to "wrap" MS UI Automation objects, and used to retrive objects inside their parent windows.

I need to understand if DynamicProxy is necessary and if it could be replaced with something faster, namely statically built classes instead of proxy classes generated at runtime, which IMO is unnecessary slowdown.

What exactly is DynamicProxy doing in the White library and can it be replaced? Any tips or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: White is just a convenient wrapper around the UI Automation library. Naturally it'd use some automatic Proxy, such as Castle. If you don't want the proxy, why won't you use UI Automation directly?

Comment: I don't understand what the proxy is used for. Is it to integrate with my user classes or does it have something to do with the internal UI automation functionality that White offers? I thought it would be harder to do it manually using MS UI Automation. Should I just start with the code in White and try to remake it without the proxy?

Comment: I haven't looked at the White code, but I would guess it'd be easier to use UI Automation directly than to rewrite White without Castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided not to use White (and instead MS UI Automation directly), but I also use Castle Dynamic Proxy in my code.  Here is a decent start at locating where it is used:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\petmongrels-white-54723f8>findstr /s  /c:"ProxyCreator" /c:"CreateClassProxy" /c:"IInterceptor" *.cs
Components\Core\Source\CustomCommands\CustomCommandInterceptor.cs:    public class   CustomCommandInterceptor : IInterceptor
Components\Core\Source\Interceptors\CoreInterceptor.cs:    public class CoreInterceptor : IInterceptor
Components\Core\Source\UIItems\UIItemContainer.cs:            var interceptors = (IInterceptor[]) interceptorField.GetValue(customUIItem);
Components\Repository\Source\Interceptors\ScreenObjectInterceptor.cs:    public class  ScreenObjectInterceptor : IInterceptor
Components\Repository\Source\Interceptors\UIItemInterceptor.cs:    public class UIItemInterceptor : IInterceptor
Components\Repository\Source\Interceptors\WindowInterceptor.cs:    public class WindowInterceptor : IInterceptor
Components\Repository\Source\Services\ServiceInterceptor.cs:    public class ServiceInterceptor : IInterceptor
```

You can get the source at:    https://github.com/petmongrels/white

(Mine is a bit out of date)

Comment: I decided not to use White either :)... its bloated and buggy. I had to rewrite the selection/scrolling logic and many other parts to make it work ... and even when it DID work it hangs up for 10 seconds per 100 list items... just to enumerate the list items. Its completely unnecessary and a mess of a library.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  White is a mess.